# Finding when a relator can be removed from group presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

There are 4 Tietze transformations and one of them is removal of superfluous relator.
Is there a mechanical approach/algorithm for deciding which relators can be removed and which cannot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relator $R_n$ can be removed if it can be derived from the other ones $R_1...R_{n-1}$. In order to check if such derivation is possible you need to check if $R_n=e$ in group $\langle A| R_1...R_{n-1} \rangle$. This is called [word problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups) and is undecidable (so there is no algorithm).

However, you can do something else. If the group is finite, you can use perform [enumeration of cosets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset_enumeration). This way you can find Cayley graph, Schreier transversal, permutation representation and most importantly a definition table with all relations necessary for the group. While this does not tell you which of the *original* relations were superfluous, you may use the "definition" column in monitor table to produce a new set of relators.

It is also worth mentioning the [Knuth-Benedix algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Bendix_completion_algorithm) for solving the word problem. You may use it to semi-decide whether a relator is not superfluous, but Knuth-Benedix may fail if the relator is superfluous.

Comment: I suspect that, even if the original group is trivial, then it is undecidable whether $R_n$ is redundant i.e. whether $\langle A \mid R_1,\ldots,R_{n-1} \rangle$ is trivial - but I am not sure about that.